# how to retrieve data from datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am unable to retrieve data from datagrid in wpf, i tried following,

My data

```
public List<DrugChart> LoadDrugDataGrid()
{
    List<DrugChart> lstdrugchart = new List<DrugChart>();
    lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet1", T01 = ""     , T02 = "" });
    lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet2", T01 = "true" , T02 = "" });
    lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet3", T01 = ""     , T02 = "" });
    lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet4", T01 = "false", T02 = "true" });
    lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet5", T01 = ""     , T02 = "" });
    lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet6", T01 = "true" , T02 = "" });
    return lstdrugchart;
}
```

Initialization

```
public partial class DrugDaily2 : UserControl
{
    DAL dd = new DAL();
    public DrugDaily2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgDrugChart1.ItemsSource = dd.LoadDrugDataGrid();
    }
}
```

For retrieving data i tried this

```
foreach (DrugChart cell in dgDrugChart1.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(cell.DrugName + cell.T01 + cell.T02);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="dd.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgDrugChart1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="299" Width="497" MouseDoubleClick="dgDrugChart1_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace dd
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgDrugChart1.ItemsSource = LoadDrugDataGrid();
        }
        public List<DrugChart> LoadDrugDataGrid()
        {
            List<DrugChart> lstdrugchart = new List<DrugChart>();
            lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet1", T01 = "", T02 = "" });
            lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet2", T01 = "true", T02 = "" });
            lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet3", T01 = "", T02 = "" });
            lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet4", T01 = "false", T02 = "true" });
            lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet5", T01 = "", T02 = "" });
            lstdrugchart.Add(new DrugChart { DrugName = "Tablet6", T01 = "true", T02 = "" });
            return lstdrugchart;
        }

        public class DrugChart
        {
            public string DrugName { get; set; }
            public string T01 { get; set; }
            public string T02 { get; set; }
        }


        private void dgDrugChart1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (DrugChart cell in dgDrugChart1.Items)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(cell.DrugName + cell.T01 + cell.T02);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            
        }
    }
}
```